# How to access a Java static method from Scala given a type alias for that class it resides in

Tags: java, scala, static-methods, type-alias

Given the type-alias `type Cal = java.util.Calendar` how can the `static` `getInstance` method be accessed? I tried the following in Scala REPL:

```
scala> type Cal = java.util.Calendar
defined type alias Cal
scala> Cal.getInstance
<console>:8: error: not found: value Cal
          Cal.getInstance
          ^
scala> val Cal = java.util.Calendar
<console>:7: error: object Calendar is not a value
   val Cal = java.util.Calendar
                       ^
```

Is `import java.util.{Calendar => Cal}` followed by `import Cal._` really my best bet?

Comment: For the sake of consistency and to have the type-alias fully substitute the type I think Scala should also make static methods accessible through it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't.

Yes, `import java.util.{Calendar => Cal}` is really your best bet.

Conceptually, Scala `object` members are similar to static members of Java classes. This might suggest the following would work, but it doesn't since there are actually no singleton objects available for Java classes.

```
scala> val Cal = java.util.Calendar
<console>:13: error: object Calendar is not a value
       val Cal = java.util.Calendar
                           ^
```

Comment: I guess you could also just go ahead and wrap the whole thing manually in an `object Cal`. One might argue what solution is **the best bet**.