# How to enrich a Java library class that has static methods (aka enrich an object in Scala)?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to extend a class (SWT.java) from a Java library (SWT) that only has `static final` members. An excerpt from the library class:

```
package org.eclipse.swt;
import org.eclipse.swt.internal.*;

public class SWT {
    public static final int None = 0;
    // ...
    public static final int MouseDown = 3;
    // ...
}
```

My Java wrapper class that worked fine in Java land:

```
public class SWT extends org.eclipse.swt.SWT {
    public static final int FinalizeText = 201;
    public static final int ParseText = 202;
}
```

Now if I try to use my new SWT class in Scala, I'll get errors like this:

```
Error:(198, 27) value MouseDown is not a member of object my.package.SWT
    table.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, periodEditListener)
                          ^
```

Ideally I would like a new `SWT` object with which I could access both original members (e.g. `MouseDown`) and members I define (e.g. `FinalizeText`).

It seems that Scala interprets everything useful about this class as an object, which is fine if we just want to use the original SWT definitions, but you [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893274/how-to-mix-in-a-trait-to-instance) [easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625040/is-there-any-way-to-extend-an-object) [extend](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/f-x_ybX6I1o) objects in Scala.

It has occurred to me that implicits *a la* [pimp my library](https://coderwall.com/p/k_1jzw/scala-s-pimp-my-library-pattern-example) might be the way to go, but even were I to get this to work, I think the solution would not be accessible from Java (still, I have not even gotten in to work in Scala).

How to best tackle the problem? Maybe the right answer is to just define a separate, unrelated object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a good way to do what you want such that:

- You can neatly tie all members to an identifier (i.e. refer to the field via `SWT.X` instead of `X`)
- Have it work both in Scala and Java.
- You don't have to manually forward fields.

This is a documented limitation of Scala -- see [access java base class's static member in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034017/access-java-base-classs-static-member-in-scala).

In addition, I don't think the implicit route works either, because you can't treat a Java class as a value: [How to access a Java static method from Scala given a type alias for that class it resides in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668262/how-to-access-a-java-static-method-from-scala-given-a-type-alias-for-that-class)

Probably the best way to do what you want is to manually forward the static members you need in `my.package.SWT`:

```
public class SWT extends org.eclipse.swt.SWT {
    public static final int FinalizeText = 201;
    public static final int ParseText = 202;
    public static int getMouseDown() {
        return MouseDown;
    }
}
```

If you only care about automatically forwarding members and not about the other requirements, you can use `import`:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT._
table.addListener(MouseDown, periodEditListener)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and references.

Answer (score 0):

I am accepting yuzeh's answer for thoroughness, general applicability, and helpfulness, but here is what I actually did, which is slightly different:

I was very tempted by yuzeh's last suggestion for the sake of uniformity, i.e.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT._
import my.package.SWT._
```

Although as my first example snippet above inadvertently shows, `SWT.None` unfortunately *is*, so bringing it into the local namespace would conflict with Option's None.

I think for now I'll just import like:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT
import my.package.{SWT => MySWT}
```

If nothing else, it is a bit more clear where the constants are coming from. There, I talked myself into believing this is better :).

Comment: You can do `import org.eclipse.swt.SWT.{None => SwtNone, _}` (or `_` to remove the import).